# Did it make sense for Daenerys to ask what "In Perpetuity" means?

Tags: game-of-thrones

After all, she is multilingual, it isn't that obscure of a word.

Comment: She's not asking whether Jon knows what it means, she's re-iterating it. It's a [Rhetorical question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question)

Comment: It sounded like she was asking because *she* was at least pretending she did not know that, indeed, it's meaning could be emphasized but I am not sure she would even pretend to not know such a term. She might have said, "And for how long was allegiance sworn?" and Tyrion might have said, "In perpetuity, my queen."

Comment: She might have said that.  She might also have said, "And so-and-so swore allegiance of all his descendants.  Are you a descendant?"  Or a million other things.  But she chose to make the point this way.  I saw nothing that suggested she didn't know what it meant.  She said it the first time like she already knew exactly what it meant, with no hesitation over the word like people have with unfamiliar words.  She later asked Tyrion to put it another way, for dramatic effect.  In fact, the whole speech sounded rehearsed, likely including that aside.

Comment: Again, she was semi-humorously pretending not to know -- I think in the past she has referred to her lack of education and this may be why she said this but I don't think she would have chosen such a basic phrase.

Comment: More pertinently, does it make sense to ask whether it makes sense to ask?

Comment: @JDoe: And then, do ad infinitum, does it make sense to ask to whether.... and then Daenerys asks what "ad infinitum" means and Tyrion says, "It's kind of like in perpetuity..."

Comment: She has always acted coy and mildly condescending when dealing with other nobles. It feels quite in line with her character.

Answer (score 13):

She is using a [rhetorical question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question) to make her point. She is implicitly saying, "look, this is obvious".

So yes, it makes sense for her to ask as it is a valid way to get her point across.

> **Daenerys:** Forgive me Ser Davos. I never did receive a formal education *[mock innocence]*, but I could have sworn I read the last King in the North was Torrhen Stark, who bent the
>   knee to my ancestor, Aegon Targaryen. In exchange for his life, and
>   the lives of the Northmen, Torrhen Stark swore fealty to House
>   Targaryen in perpetuity. *[mock confusion, rhetorical question]* But do I have my facts wrong?
>
> **Davos:** I wasn't there, Your Grace. *[evasive answer]*
>
> **Daenerys:** No. Of course not. But still, an oath is an oath. And
>   perpetuity means... *[mock confusion, rhetorical question]* What does perpetuity mean, Lord Tyrion?
>
> **Tyrion:** Forever. *[confirmation of rhetorical question]*
>
> **Daenerys:** Forever. *[with finality]*

<sup>*[descriptions mine]*</sup>

Here is the scene.

Comment: It seems to me still that Daenerys is simulating not knowing the meaning of the term, playing off her earlier mentioning of not being educated. So that it would be at least plausible that someone uneducated would not know the term but I am saying that it is too simple a term for her to make this kind of mild joke about. Like she wouldn't say, "What does 'forever' mean?" Again, I would have had it be some phrase in the equivalent of a scholarly tongue like ancient Greek or classical Chinese which she nonetheless knows the meaning of (and others know she knows) but plausibly might not know.

Comment: @Jeff I don't get your point. To remind someone of something by asking a rhetorical question the question does not have to be a hard one. She could have directly asked "For how long did lord Stark x?" - "forever" - "oh right, forever".

Comment: @Philpp: I can't explain it any more clearly than I have. It is a nuance -- the line did not work for me.